# How i can to Extract value from parametr "bidfloor" from the colomn Body to the colomn D

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

How i can extract value from parameter from the colomn   in Excel, if this parameter is presented in the form of a dictionary, for example "id":"03CD2B3C24558D83","imp": [{"id":"03CD2B3C22558D83","video":{"mimes": ["video/mp4","video/x-flv","application/x-shockwave-}. I neeed to extract a value of parameter id.

I tried the directory openpyxl, but i don't can extract the value.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: My code
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/storage/emulated/0/Download/Log.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
ws = wb.active

for cell in ws['C']:
    print(cell.value)
    But i don't know what i need to write for to extract the value

Answer (score 0):

```
The data doesn't quite fit to extract as json or even a clean list. Regex maybe the best option
 
import openpyxl 
import re


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/storage/emulated/0/Download/Log.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1') 
ws = wb.active 
pattern1 = re.compile('(?<=\"id\":\").*?(?=\",\")')
for cell in ws['C']: 
    print(cell.value)
    match = re.findall(pattern1, cell.value)
    for id in match:
        print(id)
```

03CD2B3C24558D83

03CD2B3C22558D83

Comment: How i can extract the value from Excel? Thanks

Comment: You have the value from excel, it's called cell.value. I have edited the example above to include your code